# String Arrays and how to loop them

Tags: java, arrays, control-flow

I was wondering if it is possible to make a loop for an array of strings that i want to evaluate in my code. I want to do more than one binary number at a time. So far I have this working correctly, however I cant figure our how to make it evaluate more than one binary number at a time. Thank you.

```
 package twoComplement;

public class bintodec {

public static void main (String[] args)throws java.io.IOException {

int number,
    digit1,
    digit2,
    digit3,
    digit4,
    digit5,
    digit6,
    digit7,
    digit8,
    result;

String num = "11100111";

number = Integer.parseInt(num);

digit1 = ((number % 100000000) - (number % 10000000 % 10000000)) / 10000000;
digit2 = ((number % 10000000) - (number % 10000000 % 1000000)) / 1000000;
digit3 = ((number % 1000000) - (number % 1000000 % 100000)) / 100000;
digit4 = ((number % 100000) - (number % 100000 % 10000)) / 10000;
digit5 = ((number % 10000) - (number % 10000 % 1000)) / 1000;
digit6 = ((number % 1000) - (number % 1000 % 100)) / 100;
digit7 = ((number % 100) - (number % 100 % 10)) / 10;
digit8 = (number % 10);

result = (digit1 * -128) + (digit2 * 64) + (digit3 * 32) + (digit4 * 16) + (digit5 * 8) + (digit6 * 4) + (digit7 * 2) + (digit8 * 1);

System.out.println ( "Binary number: " + num + "\nDecimal Number: " + result);
System.out.println();
System.exit( 0 );

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the purpose of *loops* ;-) An *advanced for* loop is the best way to iterate through an array. You can also iterate through collections (IE: `ArrayList`), which makes it easier to add new items.

```
String[] numbersToEvaluate = new String[]{"11100111", "100101", "10101101"};

for (String num: numbersToEvaluate)
{
    number = Integer.parseInt(num);

    digit1 = ((number % 100000000) - (number % 10000000 % 10000000)) / 10000000;
    digit2 = ((number % 10000000) - (number % 10000000 % 1000000)) / 1000000;
    digit3 = ((number % 1000000) - (number % 1000000 % 100000)) / 100000;
    digit4 = ((number % 100000) - (number % 100000 % 10000)) / 10000;
    digit5 = ((number % 10000) - (number % 10000 % 1000)) / 1000;
    digit6 = ((number % 1000) - (number % 1000 % 100)) / 100;
    digit7 = ((number % 100) - (number % 100 % 10)) / 10;
    digit8 = (number % 10);

    result = (digit1 * -128) + (digit2 * 64) + (digit3 * 32) + (digit4 * 16) + (digit5 * 8) + (digit6 * 4) + (digit7 * 2) + (digit8 * 1);

    System.out.println ( "Binary number: " + num + "\nDecimal Number: " + result);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you very much. I will mark as the answer when possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to define string array:

```
int n = 10;
String[] arr = new String[n];
```

And here is how to iterate over array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = "element number " + i;
}
```

or this way:

```
for (String element : arr) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running at least Java 5, you can use a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) construct to loop over any arbitrary Array or Collection.

```
String[] nums = //init
for (String num:nums) {
    // Do work.
}
```

If, however, you are on Java 1.4 or earlier, or you care about the index of the array, you need to use a traditional for loop

```
String[] nums = //init
for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    String num = nums[i];
    // Do work.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
for (String num : "11100111,1010,11111,110101010101010101011101010101010101010101".split(",")) {
    long result = Long.parseLong(num, 2);
    System.out.println("Binary number: " + num + ", Decimal Number: " + result);
}
```

prints

```
Binary number: 11100111, Decimal Number: 231
Binary number: 1010, Decimal Number: 10
Binary number: 11111, Decimal Number: 31
Binary number: 110101010101010101011101010101010101010101, Decimal Number: 3665040856405
```

Comment: The built-in Integer.parseInt() conversion is nearly cheating :)

Comment: @ggrigery It shouldn't be a problem unless this is `[homework]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's pretty easy.

```
String[] array = {"first", "second", "third"};
for (String element : array) {
   // do whatever
}
```

As an aside, however, you may wish to consider the following for clearer code.

```
String num = "1000";
int digit1 = Character.digit(num.charAt(0), 2);
// if you are only expecting a binary number then the second argument (2)
// tells the digit method to throw an error if it gets a digit other than 0 or 1
...
```

If this is for a school exercise or similar you may wish to test your code against the builtin  Integer parser.

```
int numFromBinaryString = Integer.parseInt(numberString, 2);
// again, here the second argument tells parseInt to interpret numberString as
// binary string
```